# SQL update script to update multiple rows in nested JSON field

Tags: sql, json

I am needing to clean up some data in a SQL Server table where the first and last name are in one JSON field and I need to separate them into individual fields. I am able to properly separate the names, but my problem is writing the proper update statement to update the data. Here is what the JSON data looks like in the database.

```
{
    "description": "firefighter injuring his back.",
    "litigation": false,
    "refRelatedCircumstanceId": null,
    "injuredWorkers": [
        {
            "firstName": "Smoth, Jimmy",
            "lastName": null,
            "occupation": null
        }
    ],
    "hasSubLobConflict": false,
    "hasLimitRetentionConflict": false
}
```

Here is an example of how I can properly separate the data when I SELECT it.

```
select c.ClaimId, c.ClaimNo, co.ClaimOptionId,  iw.FirstName, iw.LastName, 
case when CHARINDEX(',',iw.firstname) > 1 then LEFT(iw.firstname,CHARINDEX(',',iw.firstname)-1)
else iw.firstname
end  as NewLastName,
case when CHARINDEX(',',iw.firstname) > 1 then TRIM(RIGHT(iw.firstname,LEN(iw.firstname) - CHARINDEX(',',iw.firstname)))
else NULL
end  as NewFirstName
FROM 
  claim c
  JOIN claim_option co on c.ClaimId = co.ClaimId
  JOIN ref_lob lob on c.RefLobId = lob.RefLobId
  CROSS APPLY OpenJson(co.JsonData)
  WITH (
        InjuredWorkers nvarchar(max) '$.injuredWorkers' AS JSON
    ) jd
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (InjuredWorkers, '$')
    WITH (
        FirstName nvarchar(max) '$.firstName',
        LastName nvarchar(max) '$.lastName'
    ) iw
    WHERE lob.Description = 'WC'
    and iw.lastname is null
```

My problem is the proper UPDATE statement. Here is what I have:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SELECT @stm = STRING_AGG(
    CONCAT(
    'UPDATE Claim_Option ',
    'SET JsonData = JSON_MODIFY(JsonData, ''$.injuredWorkers.firstName'', case when CHARINDEX('','',''', iw.firstname ,''') > 1 then TRIM(RIGHT(''', iw.firstname ,''',LEN(''', iw.firstname ,''') - CHARINDEX('','',''', iw.firstname ,'''))) else NULL end) ',
    'WHERE ClaimOptionID = ', co.ClaimOptionID, ';'),' ')

FROM 
  claim c
  JOIN claim_option co on c.ClaimId = co.ClaimId
  JOIN ref_lob lob on c.RefLobId = lob.RefLobId
  CROSS APPLY OpenJson(co.JsonData)
  WITH (
        InjuredWorkers nvarchar(max) '$.injuredWorkers' AS JSON
    ) jd
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (InjuredWorkers, '$')
    WITH (
        FirstName nvarchar(max) '$.firstName',
        LastName nvarchar(max) '$.lastName'
    ) iw
WHERE lob.Description = 'WC' and iw.lastname is null

PRINT @stm

EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

The statement runs without error, but it does not update the firstName field. (I haven't added logic to update the lastName field yet).
I feel like I am not using the correct path, but don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I was able to figure this out. I need to add an index to the $.injuredWorkers.firstName, so that it reads $.injuredWorkers[0].firstName